# The limit of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-integration

If $f(z)$ is continuous in the neighborhood of the point $z=a$, then $$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \int_{\vert z-a\vert =r} \frac{f(z) dz}{z-a}=2\pi i\,f(a)\tag{1}$$

In my desperate intents of proving the above exercise, I tried to prove a 'particular' case of it, which is when $z=0$.

So if $z=0$ and as $f$ is continuous on a neighborhood of zero, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(re^{i \theta})-f(0)|\le \epsilon$ for $r\in[0,\delta)$ and $\theta\in\mathbb R$. Hence,

$\left\lvert\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \theta})-f(0))d\theta\right| <2\pi\epsilon \Rightarrow \limsup_{r\to0}\left\lvert\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \theta})-f(0))d\theta\right| \le2\pi\epsilon.$

If $\epsilon\to0$, then $\limsup_{r\to0}\left\lvert\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \theta})-f(0))d\theta\right|=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{r\to0}\int_{0}^{2 \pi}(f(re^{i \theta})-f(0))d\theta=0.$

Is this proof correct?

How can I make the proof for $(1)$ following the 'particular proof'?
Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't set a dummy integration variable to a specific value for a special case; that makes no sense.

Comment: I guess you mean $a=0$. The idea is good. You can make a quick fix so that  your proof works for any $a$.

Comment: yes a=0, then z=0 @SangchulLee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is nice. You can extended it to the general case by a change of variables as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_{|z-a|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz&=\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{f(a+re^{i\theta})}{re^{i\theta}}ire^{i\theta}\,d\theta\\
&=\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(a+z)}{z}\,dz
\end{align}
Since the function $g(z)=f(z+a)$ is continuous around $z=0$, we use what  you have proved and get:
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{g(z)}{z}\,dz=2\pi ig(0)=2\pi i f(a)
\end{align}
And therefore the claim follows.